# Trouble merging two linked lists in C

Tags: c, algorithm, merge, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am supposed to write a function to merge (put one at the end of another) two singly linked lists. The user inputs a series of numbers into the console, for example: 1 2 3 4 0 (0 signifies the end of input and is not an element of the list). These numbers are put into the linked list, the list now looks like this: 1 2 3 4. The process repeats again until we have two different linked lists. Then the merging function is called "void  merge(struct Node head1, struct Node head2)". Programs ends after the new list is printed.

My thought process would be to first have my pointer point at the end of the first list, then just make a while loop that will go through the other list and make the next element of the first list the current element of the second list.

```
typedef struct Element Element;

struct Element
{
    int data;
    Element *next;
};

Element *addNew(int data)
{
    Element *newN = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element));

    newN->data = data;
    newN->next = NULL;

    return newN;
}

Element *add_on_beginning(Element *head, Element *newN)
{
    newN->next = head;

    return newN;
}

Element *add_on_end(Element *head, Element *newN)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        return newN;
    }

    Element *temp = head;

    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp->next = newN;

    return head;
}

void printElement(Element *element)
{
    printf("%d ", element->data);
}

void printList(Element *head)
{
    Element *temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printElement(temp);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void merge(Element *head1, Element *head2)
{
    Element *temp1 = head1;
    Element *temp2 = head2;

    while(temp1->next != NULL)
    {
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }

    while(temp2->next != NULL)
    {
        temp1->next = temp2;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Element *head1 = NULL;
    Element *head2 = NULL;

    int arr[1000];
    char temp1;
    char temp2;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf("Input the first set of elements: \n");

    while(temp1 != '\n')
    {
        scanf("%d%c", &arr[i], &temp1);

        if(arr[i] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        head1 = add_on_end(head1, addNew(arr[i]));

        i++;
    }

    printf("Input the second set of elements: \n");

    while(temp2 != '\n')
    {
        scanf("%d%c", &arr[j], &temp2);

        if(arr[j] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        head2 = add_on_end(head2, addNew(arr[j]));

        j++;
    }

    merge(head1, head2);

    printList(head1);

    return 0;
}
```

So for some reason, the function only reads last two elements of the second list.

INPUT:

```
1 2 3 4 0
5 6 7 8 0
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 2 3 4 7 8
```

The result I'm supposed to get is

INPUT:

```
1 2 3 4 0
5 6 7 8 0
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Not your problem, but I suggest sticking with simpler invocations of `scanf`. Don't bother with `%c` and seeing if there was a newline.  But do check `scanf`'s return value, and only proceed it it's 1.

Comment: You want to make the `next` element at the end of the first list point at the *head* of the second list.  In `merge()`, there's no need to scan the second list at all.

Comment: That actually worked, I can't believe I was so stupid not to see that...So for anyone that's looking at this post in the future, in the function merge, just get rid of the second while loop and instead write temp->next = head2, thats all. @SteveSummit thanks for all the help!

Comment: As written, your `merge` function can't handle the case that the first list is NULL.  To handle that (and in keeping with the way your other functions, like `add_on_end`, are written), you'd want to have `merge` return the new list.

Comment: While the description of tag [tag:merge] is generic enough, I'd avoid the term *merge* for a union of data structures without O(1) *"random"/indexed access* if it was not *keeping the order each of the structures shows individually*. *join*, *chain*, *concatenate*, (*unite*?), …

Comment: Why does the `merge()` function return `void`? (I would expect it to return a pointer to the first element of the merged chain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
void merge(Element *head1, Element *head2)
{
    Element *temp1 = head1;
    Element *temp2 = head2;

    while(temp1->next != NULL)
    {
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }

    while(temp2->next != NULL)
    {
        temp1->next = temp2;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
}
```

is invalid.

First of all it does not change the original pointers head1 and head2 because they are passed to the function by value. So the function deals with copies of the original pointers.

Secondly in the function there is no check whether `head1` or `head2` is equal to `NULL`.

The function can be defined the following way

```
void merge( Element **head1, Element **head2 )
{
    if ( *head1 == NULL )
    {
        *head1 = *head2;
        *head2 = NULL;
    }
    else if ( *head2 != NULL )
    {
        while ( *head1 != NULL ) head1 = &( *head1 )->next;

        for ( ; *head2 != NULL; head2 = &( *head2 )->next )
        {
            *head1 = *head2;
            head1 = &( *head1 )->next;
        }
    }              
}
```

Pay attention to that there is no need to declare an array to input data in the list.

Also these while loops

```
    char temp1;
    char temp2;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf("Input the first set of elements: \n");

    while(temp1 != '\n')
    //..
```

and

```
   while(temp2 != '\n')
   //...
```

has undefined behavior because neither `temp1` nor `temp2` are initialized.

Comment: Why assign `*head2 = NULL` conditionally (if `*head1 == NULL`), only? `merge()` can sure be defined as shown in the 1st revision, but see the 2nd part of [Victor Dominguez Muñoz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57630991/3789665).

Comment: @Victor Dominguez Muñoz's Because in other case head2 will be set to NULL due to loops.

Comment: Nah - either use a separate pointer not featuring *head* as a name part to iterate the list (may be a good idea, anyway), or do some diligent shuffling after iterating the list specified by (`*`)`head1`.

Comment: @greybeard U have not understood what you want to say. As I said the original pointer header2 is set to NULL due to the for loop. So there is no need and it is just a bad idea to introduce a separate pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Think "code reuse".
You've already written the functionality you want. Reuse it...

```
printList( add_on_end( head1, head2 ) );
```

You've used `malloc()` to grab space for your nodes from the heap.
`main()` exits immediately, but it's good practice to at least acknowledge in a comment that you're not iteratively calling `free()`.

*Edit* `printList()` could be shifted into `main()` and its "final traversal" of the linked list used to make those calls to `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is:

```
while(temp2->next != NULL) {
    temp1->next = temp2;
    temp2 = temp2->next;
}
```

You are not updating the value of temp1.

Also, why don't you just instead of this second while do:

```
temp1->next = temp2;
```

I mean linked list 2 is properly linked, you just need to link the end of the first list with the beginning of the second.